# Moderator Means Output from R

Tags: r

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this table:

[image]

For example, do I interpret line 3 as a MOOSES_Rating of 5 is has a .07 effect size higher than the reference category? This difference isn't statistically significant at the 10% level, because the p-value is .281.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting the results from statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick!

Comment: @MrFlick, if you do know how to read this table, do you mind helping me understand it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482013/moderator-means-output ? Thanks!